# Automatically Display data without click on Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with search form , I want them without pressing the search button, it should work when loading the page.

Html code :

```
<form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return search()">
<div>
<div class="input-holder">
<input type="text" id="query" value="test" class="search-input"/>
<button  class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span>search</span></button>
</div>
<span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
<div class="result-container">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Do note that using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Thank you sir  @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can accomplish @CetainPerformance excellent advice.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

// Load input text query with value 'test'
$('#query').val('test');

});

// Add onclick event to span class .close
$( ".search-icon" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log('span class .search-icon was Clicked.' );
});

// Add onclick event to span class .close
$( ".close" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log('span class .close was Clicked.' );
});

// Add onsubmit event to form id #search-form
$( "#search-form" ).on( "submit", function() {
  console.log('form id #search-form was submitted.' );
});
```

```css
.close {

cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form" name="search-form">
<div>

<div class="input-holder">

<input type="text" id="query" value="test" class="search-input"/>
<button  class="search-icon">Search</button>
<span class="close">[Close X]</span>

</div>

<div class="result-container">
</div>

</div>

</form>
```

**Every time you click search**, you must clicked **Run code snipet again**. This is because the form is submitted.